# Codeigniter Load library/model in config files

Tags: codeigniter, model, load

How can I load or library or model in config/database.php file?

Im using CodeIgniter v2

Regards, Mario

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why you would want to do this. Libraries and models are not supposed to be loaded in config files. Config files are for static configuration options only. Could you provide some more information as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like to use multiple database connection. Database connection details are saved in MySQL database...

Comment: The app would need the connection details to connect to the database in the first place. So without connection details, how would it be able to retrieve connection details from the database? You should place your database configuration details in config/database.php.

Comment: I have my primary details (codeigniter system). In this one, I would like to get products from other database. I would like to get products from another database dynamic, so you can enter second database details via form in PHP. Codeigniter system must create second DB with details from database..

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you are thinking of autoloading - Look at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html
Maybe that solves your problem.